# Как собрать html обекты по количестве элементов массива?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть массив url-лок. Нужно по количестве url-лов в массивчике собрать теги img. Img-шный тег должен содержать класс "tableBanner1".

Вот например массив :

```
 var masive_picture  =    ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8b/Proton-K-Zarya.jpg/800px-Proton-K-Zarya.jpg", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/3/31/Winniethepooh.jpg" ]
```

А нужно чтоб получилось:

```
<img class="tableBanner1"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8b/Proton-K-Zarya.jpg/800px-Proton-K-Zarya.jpg" />
<img class="tableBanner1"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/3/31/Winniethepooh.jpg" />
```

Знаю что нужно пройтись по массиву цыклом но не знаю как это должно выглядить синтаксически. Подскажите кто знает как это сделать ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из способов

```
var text = '';
for (var i = 0; i < masive_picture.length; ++i) {
    text += '<img class="tableBanner1" src="' + masive_picture[i] + '" />'
}
```

Можно тег `img` создавать динамически на яваскрите. Но тогда нужно будет указать явно контейнер, куда это все добавлять